# $L(x) \leq U(x)$ & $L'(x)$ and $U'(x)$ exist. Assume there's a pt c st. $U(c)=L(c)$. Consider $U(x)-L(x)$ and show that $c$ is a min of this function

Tags: optimization

Question and attempt at question are in the photo below. I have gotten halfway through but I am confused how to show the rest of the question (mainly part c)

Thanks for your help in advance :)

[image: Questions highlighted and attempt below]

Comment: Note: Use \$\phi\$ for $\phi$.

Comment: If someone could please help it would be greatly appreciated. if $\phi$'(c)=0 I am unsure how to use this to show u'(c)=L'(c). Is it just as simple as saying $\phi$'(c)=u'(c)-L'(c)=0 So u'(c)=L'(c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $2(b)$ right.

$2(c)\;$ Your statement of the theorem is almost right. It needs the restriction that the function must be differentiable at the min/max point $c$. (For an example of why that's needed, consider a V-shaped function: it has a minimum at the bottom of the V but has no derivative at that point.)

Now, $\phi$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ because both $U$ and $L$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

So by your theorem, $\phi'(c) = 0$.

Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(x) &=& U(x) - L(x) \\
\phi'(x) &=& U'(x) - L'(x) \\
\phi'(c) &=& U'(c) - L'(c) \\
0 &=& U'(c) - L'(c) \\
U'(c) &=& L'(c). \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for your help Mick. Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the *derivative* of
$\phi'(c)$ that is zero,
but $\phi'(c)$ itself.

Comment: sorry thats what I meant. accidentally wrote it out as well as putting in the symbol